# SQL Select Query With FIND_IN_SET Or Any things else to find comma separated values in a column with comma separeted values

Tags: sql, select, find-in-set

I have one column having comma separated values:

```
id Column_name
== ==========
1  value1,value2,value3,value5
2  value2,value3,value4
3  value1,value3,value5
4  value1,value2,value4,value5
```

Now, I want a query that get all records having `value2` OR `value4`

I need query like below if possible:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET('value2,value4',`column_name`)
```

So, it will return recode with id `1,2,4` (having `value2` or `value4`)

I have form for user that send `value1,value2 ..etc` from check_box

How can I optimize my select Query?

Comment: You cannot optimize a query that uses string operations for searching lists.  You need to structure your data properly, using a junction/association table.

Answer (score 3):

Use it like this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('value2',column_name) > 0
or FIND_IN_SET('value4',column_name) > 0
```

### But never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

You should actually rather change your DB structure to something like this

```
your_table
----------
id
name
other_columns


values table
------------
your_table_id
value
```